# error A2070: invalid instruction operands how do I fix this

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So I have program that is supposed to identify if one word(s1) is an anagram of another(s2).
But I keep getting error A2070: invalid instruction operands on lines 15 34 and 36. I have looked up the error but I can't seem to find a solution to or understand it.

All I have tried is changing the movzx's to mov's for the lines specified but this makes the program throw and exception. If the program works it is supposed to change the value in eax to 1 from 0.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    s1 byte "GARDEN"
    s2 byte "DANGER"
    c1 byte 26 dup(0)               ;counter for each letter in s1
    c2 byte 26 dup(0)               ;counter for each letter in s2
.code
    main proc
        mov eax, 0                  ;we will assume that we do not have an anagram
    
        movzx ebx, lengthof s1      ;(1) iterate lengthof s1 times

        mov esi, 0                  ;start at the first byte of s1 and s2

        CounterLoop:                ;this will increment the proper 'elements' of c1 and c2
            movzx edi, s1[esi]      ;move the value from s1 into edi

            inc c1[edi - 65]        ;(2) increment the counter at the value - 65. 
                                    ;subtract 65 because the ASCII value of A is 65, B is 66, C is 67...
                                    ;when you subtract 65 then the sum of all the As will be stored in 'index' 0
                                    ;Bs in 'index' 1, Cs in 'index' 2...

            movzx edi, s2[esi]      ;(3) Do the same procedure for s2

            inc c2[edi - 65]        ;(4) increment the second counter at the value - 65.
 
            inc esi                 ;increment esi
            loop CounterLoop        ;after this loop terminates our couter arrays will have the proper values

        movzx esi, 0                ;(5) start checking the counter arrays at 'index' 0

        movzx ebx, lengthof c1      ;(6)iterate lengthof c1 times

        VerifyLoop:         
            mov bl, c1              ;(7) move value of c1 into bl

            cmp bl, c2              ;(8) check bl vs the value of c2

            jmp NoAna               ;(9) if they are not equal then we do not have an anagram.  jump to NoAna

            inc esi                 ;increment esi
            loop VerifyLoop
        
        mov eax, 1              ;if the loop terminates and we have not jumped then we know we have an anagram

      

        NoAna:
            invoke ExitProcess, 0

    main endp
end main
```

Comment: `movzx ebx, lengthof s1` doesn't make sense; movzx doesn't take an immediate operand.  Use `mov ebx, lengthof s1` to put an assemble-time-constant number into a register.  If your program crashes after fixing that bug, you have other bugs.  Use a debugger to single-step and look at register values.

Comment: Also your `VerifyLoop` is not iterating the arrays since it always loads from `c1` and `c2`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> loop CounterLoop
> ```

The `loop` instruction depends on ECX, not on EBX that you have set up.
Write `mov ecx, LENGTHOF s1` instead.
Better still, don't use the slow `loop` instruction and write it like:

```
...
inc  esi
cmp  esi, LENGTHOF s1
jb   CounterLoop
```

Your second loop can use the same trick to replace `loop VerifyLoop`. This loop has some additional problems:

- This `jmp NoAna` must become a **conditional jump** `jne NoAna`.
- The `inc esi` currently serves no purpose since you don't use it to address consecutive bytes in the *c1* and *c2* arrays.

```
    xor   eax, eax

    ...

    xor   esi, esi
VerifyLoop:         
    movzx edx, c1[esi]
    cmp   dl, c2[esi]
    jne   NoAna
    inc   esi
    cmp   esi, LENGTHOF c1
    jb    VerifyLoop
    inc   eax  ;if the loop terminates and we have not jumped then we know we have an anagram
NoAna:
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
```